# Rounding total minutes from a field to populate hours to another field

Tags: javascript, pdf, acrobat

I am working on a fillable PDF and need a script that will round the total minutes populated into a form field that will populate the nearest hour into another field.

Example: `total minutes displayed as 1240 (field 1) = 20.67 hours, should display 21 hours in field 2.`

Comment: Can you use external libraries as moment.js? (https://momentjs.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Readable code:

```
minutes = this.getField('total minutes').value;
fullHours = Math.floor(minutes/60); 
remainingMinutes = minutes % 60;
hoursRounded = fullHours + (remainingMinutes<30?0:1) ;
```

Less readable code:

```
Math.round( Math.floor(this.getField('total minutes').value / 30 ) / 2.0)
```

Answer (score -1):

Add the code below to a custom calculation script in the "hours" field. Replace the name of the field in the code below with the actual field name of your "total minutes" field.

```
event.target.value = Math.round(this.getField('total minutes').value);
```

[image]

Comment: did you test it? How should Math.round know that it should round a number of minutes to a number of hours?